# IIR Filter Design Issues : MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter-design

I am designing an IIR Filter with the following designs constraints:

1. Passband $(0.75\pi,\pi)$
2. Stopband $(0,0.70\pi)$
3. No more than $0.5$ % ripple in the passband
4. No less than $40$ dB attenuation in the stopband

Using the `designfilt` command I am able to design the filter.

However when I am using the following code for the "Butteworth" filter I do not get any Phase response. The magnitude response is fine, but the Phase values have NaN values - "Not a Number". The same codes are able to design for "Chebyshev" and "Elliptic" filters.

```
Wp = 0.75;
Ws = 0.7;
Rp = 20*log10(1.005);
Rs = 40;

[Nb, Wnb] = buttord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs); % Nb: minimum order; Wnb: cutoff frequency
[Zb, Pb, Kb] = butter(Nb, Wnb,'high'); % Zb : zeros ; Pb : Poles , Kb : gain

SOSb = zp2sos(Zb, Pb, Kb);

freqz(SOSb)
```

Response for Butterworth Filter

[image]

Response for Chebyshev I filter

[image]

Comment: I think its due to the order of the butterworth filter. Its 34 { because of the sharp transition width }.

Comment: Have you tried `[b,a]=butter(Nb, Wnb,'high');` and `freqz(b,a)`?

Comment: Yeah I had Matt. It also did not work. Returned phase values only for half of the frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a bug in the `freqz` implementation. I didn't dig enough to figure out why but even this doesn't work:

```
freqz(SOSb(1:2,:));
```

Even though `angle(freqz(SOSb(1:2,:)))` returns a legitimate result.

But I found this as a workaround:

```
[h,f,s]=freqz(SOSb);
freqzplot(h,f,s);
```

Unfortunately `freqzplot` is being obsoleted so you might have to resort to:

```
plot(angle(freqz(SOSb)));
```